# Exception refuses to be handled

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I tried two ways of catching unexpected unhandled exceptions:

```
static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
                new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandler.HandleException);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            try
            {
                Application.Run(new OCR());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorWindow errorWindow = new ErrorWindow(ex);
                errorWindow.ShowDialog();
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

When i execute the application using visual studio, everything works fine. if i use exe file in the bin\Debug folder, the exceptions are not handled. Application behaves as if catch block wasn't there. I'm clueless what's going on. any ideas?

edit: exceptio nis not thron in **Load**

Comment: Maybe more specifics as to what sort of exception it is could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should handle System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException - then it works.

Comment: still don't know what's wrong with try catch block but at least the handler works fine.

Comment: Or there was another exception handler along the way that already caught it.

Comment: I was going to answer your question by suggesting to handle that event. It does not have to be in the Load event, it may be anywhere in a code executed in a thread other than the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you have an exception in your Form's `OnLoad` method or `Load` event, then. This is a notorious issue, which isn't helped by the IDE making it behave differently. Basically, you need to make sure that your `OnLoad`/`Load` don't throw... perhaps put the `catch` in there, and set a property you can check afterwards?

Comment: well that's true! i did put it in load to see what happens. but before that i had an exception thrown in a different part of code, long after load. i didn't have the try catch block then but a had the UnhandledException handler and it wasn't fired as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into an interesting issue when dealing with J# code.

Assume that the exception being thrown is of type `FreakyException`. Now, `FreakyException` inherits from `FreakyExceptionBase` class, which in turn inherits from `Exception` class. The trick is that each of them are defined in their own assemblies. Say, `FreakyExceptionBase` resides in `ExceptionBases.dll`, but `FreakyException` itself resides in `Worker.dll`. Your application only references the `Worker.dll`, but NOT the `ExceptionBases.dll`.

In this case your `catch(Exception)` won't catch `FreakyException` because .NET will not be able to figure out the inheritance chain that specifies that `FreakyException` actually inherits form `Exception`.

This happened with J# code because J# exceptions inherit from `java.lang.exception`, and my project wasn't referencing J# libraries. When J# was referenced, the problem went away.

Perhaps it is the same case with your application?

Comment: not really because i was throwing ArgumentException and it inherits from system.exception from sure.  
it's good to know what you've written though.